# AngularJS variable is set, but not visible in different DIV

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm braking my head over this:

```
      <label>Modiality:</label>
             <select ng-model="sysinfo.modiality" required>
                   <option value="">Please select...</option>
                   <option required data-ng-repeat="modiality in modialityTypeController.items" value="{{modiality.Name}}">{{modiality.Name}}</option>
              </select>                      

                    <p>{{sysinfo.modiality}}</p>
```

The `<p>` is there to proof that my binding works.

Then in another div i'm doing this:

```
<h1>{{sysinfo.modiality}}</h1>
```

But nothing shows up.... !?

Since the binding proofs it's working properly in the `<p>` what could possibly the reason that it doesn't work in a different DIV that's i might have overlooked?

Comment: Does this div lies in the same controller?

Comment: hard to guess without the complete markup. Be careful with scopes, ng-if/ng-repeat for example create their own scopes, so their scope variables outside will be invisible. You can check this approach my making your sysinfo not a scope, but a controller variable.

Comment: yes they do...  

As a matter of fact, It's basically a copy of 2 other divs that work perfectly fine...

Comment: ok thanks for the tip @tratto  I will definitely keep that in mind...

Comment: It seems a total reboot solved the issue... for now.... still I'm a bit clueless about what's the real reason :(

Comment: Show us your jsfiddle